# Manage the test connection in e2e nestjs

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I'm trying to create a database only for e2e test, but when I need to delete it, I delte the main database.

the problem should be the getConnectionToken because I use it during the drop database but it gets the main connection
in my beforeEach I have

```
const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        
        MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
          useFactory: () => ({
            uri: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test',
            name: 'testing_connection',            
          })
        }),        
        AppModule,
        AuthModule,
        UsersModule
      ]
    }).compile();
```

and in my AfterAll I have

```
afterAll(async () => {
    await (app.get(getConnectionToken()) as Connection).db.dropDatabase();
    await app.close();
  });
```

During the test, I'm able to write on the test database, but in the After All I drop the main Connection.
If I check the `app.get(getConnectionToken()` I can see that I have two connections, the first one is the connection that I create on `app.module`, the second one should be the test connection.

The question is, how can I drop the right database? I can pass a param in `getConnectionToken`, I tried with `testing_connection` but without lucky

Comment: I'm not having multiple connections so this might not help you but what I did to drop a database was to create a custom provider `DBService` which I inject a connection `constructor(@InjectConnection() private conn: Connection) {}` and I add a method `dropDb` which is going `this.conn.dropDb()`. Maybe it helps you. Otherwise you might get more help on Discord: https://discord.gg/uWbZyD5cK5

Answer (score 0):

You should add `await app.init()` in `beforeEach` or `beforeAll` function for initializing the Nest application .If you use single connection try:

```
const connection = app.get(getConnectionToken()); "DatabaseConnection"
await connection.dropDatabase();
```

If you use multiple connection, you should replace `getConnectionToken()` by connection name (in your case is `testing_connection`)